# Project files in Gitlab

Tags: git, ubuntu, gitlab, webhooks

I installed `Gitlab` on my Ubuntu server using the [Omnibus package](https://about.gitlab.com/installation/#ubuntu) and created a project.

I want to add a `post-receive`-webhook to it to automatically deploy to my webserver. The [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/repository_storage_paths.html#configure-gitlab) say the default repository path for Omnibus package installations is `/var/opt/gitlab/git-data` and indeed my project's directory is a git repository.

My problem is, there are no project files. Everything I can find there are the default git folders like config, description, HEAD, hooks, etc.

Where are the actual project files stored?

Edit:
I just found out that the project files of a bare git repo (Gitlab respos are usually - maybe always - bare) are not really existing.

Nevertheless Gitlab knows the file structure behind my project and every file's content. But how does it do that?

And if I add a remote to this repository, what exactly gets pushed when I call `git push`?

Comment: You might find this similar question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38945741/gitlab-post-receive-deploy helpful. The linked documentation includes a section called "Using Git Hooks to Deploy to a Separate Production Server".

Comment: Well, in that section it says it's about deploying to a seperate server, but they are using local paths with `git --work-tree=/var/www/html --git-dir=/home/demo/proj checkout -f`. And with the checkout command I can't use external paths with ssh as I can do it with `git push`. I already tried that.